# Can not import opencv and dlib in anaconda enviroment

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, dlib

When i create a project by Pycharm in Anconda environment, use : `conda info --envs` i get this :

```
    base                     C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3
    env_dlib                 C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\env_dlib
    opencv-env               C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\opencv-env
```

then use command :        `conda activate env_dilb` i can import dlib easily by using this command :`python` then `import dlib`, but i can not import cv2 by `import cv2`, it get notice : "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'".

And conversely when i use `conda activate opencv-env`, I can only do
  `import cv2`.
How can i import two of both, and some other libraries too.

Comment: what is the output of "conda list" and "pip freeze" commands after activating environment "env_dlib"

Comment: output of "conda list:" ```certifi
dlib
intel-openmp
jpeg
libblas
libcblas
liblapack
libpng
mkl
numpy
pip
python
setuptools
sqlite
vc
vs2015_runtime
wheel
wincertstore
zlib```

Comment: and output of "pip freeze": ```certifi==2019.9.11
numpy==1.17.3
wincertstore==0.2```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the environment "dlib" package is available but "opencv" is not available.

Please follow the below steps to install opencv in the environment:

```
conda activate env_dlib
pip install opencv-python
```

After that try importing opencv using below command:

```
import cv2
```